# ipython widget button that refreshes a table

Tags: python, widget, jupyter, jupyter-lab, ipywidgets

I'm having issues with a simple code.

I'm using jupyterlab and I have a cell that creates a widget with 3 buttons. It then executes the "model" function:

```
from ipywidgets import *

wid = interactive(model, months=widgets.ToggleButtons(options=['3m','6m','9m'], description='months'))

display(wid)
```

The model function returns a dataframe called pred_df.

Then I have another cell where I'm having the problem. I want to have a button that refreshes a display of the dataframe.

```
button = widgets.Button(description="Refresh")

display(button)

def on_button_clicked(b):
    pred_df = wid.result
    pred_df = pred_df.sort_values(by='Predicted returns', ascending=False)
    print(pred_df.head(10))
    
button.on_click(on_button_clicked)
```

The problem here, I think, is that the display is printing the button over the print method, is it still shows in the console log.

Is there a way I can resolve this?

Comment: Can you share a screenshot?

Comment: You probably want to direct the result of sorting back to the widget instead of printing them? This question is difficult to answer as it is not a reproducible example and does not explain your problem clearly.

Comment: @krassowski yea you were right. I figured it out and posted an answer.

Answer (score 0):

I figured how to do this:

```
button = widgets.Button(description="Refresh!")
output = widgets.Output()

display(button, output)

def on_button_clicked(b):
    pred_df = wid.result
    pred_df = pred_df1.sort_values(by='Predicted returns', ascending=False)
    with output:
        clear_output(wait = False)
        display(pred_df.head(10)) 


button.on_click(on_button_clicked)
```